# Bumping floating blocks a line up or down

Tags: css, css-float

I am in lack of better words to describe my problem, which prevents me from researching the issue properly. However, I can describe it.

Below is my result so far. The elements in question will reside in a table-cell, in a table with a lot of data. The items in blue are the div-elements which I want to move horizontally, such that their left border shows the "value" of the element. In the example below, the value is shown in parentheses, in respect to the entire cells width. The width of the elements is fluid, as the elements will contain text of different lengths.

[image]

(See image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Iy7.png)

This was obtained with the following code:

```
td.singleton {display: table-cell; }
td.singleton > div {display: inline-block; background-color: blue; clear: both; float:left}

<tr class="level2"><td>&nbsp;</td><td colspan="7" class="singleton">
        <div style="margin-left: 12%">Item 1 (.12)</div>
        <div style="margin-left: 23%">Item 2 (.23)</div>
        <div style="margin-left: 40%">Item 3 (.40)</div>
        <div style="margin-left: 80%">Item 4 (.80)</div>
</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Currently, the above works fine and the data is readable. However, I want the four "lines" compacted to two, as below:

[image]

( See image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Pyv.png)

Here, the elements are drawn on the upper-most line, as long as they do not lie on top of a previous element; in this case, the element is "bumped down" a line.
The generation of the html is done in Python, so as a last resort, it might be possible to determine which line to use manually instead of letting the browser decide.

Now there is a two-fold question:

1. How would you describe my problem with only a few words, so I can further investigate?
2. Is this possible using css?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would describe this as "vertical floating".

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't think you can achieve this in CSS. You're better off doing that intelligence in python...</strike>

After reading your question again and playing with the code you provided (and making the font color to white ;)), I found that, you might stand a chance by playing with position. The first step is probably to make the `div`s absolutely positioned...

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with css only. You'll need js. I'd recommend jQuery http://jquery.com/
You'll need to keep track of position of the elements http://api.jquery.com/position/ and then check to see if the next element's position causes the overlay.

As far as css there's a number of ways... if you want just a collection of divs try experimenting with position: absolute; on each of those and using top and left instead of margins (parent will have to have position: relative).

You could also try wrapping each row in a separate div, but you can probably get away without doing that.

On the separate note -- what's going to happen with your element if it's margin-left (or left in my scenario) is more than total width - element width? How will it look like for an element positioned at 95%?

Comment: Response to the separate note; I too have pondered about that, and I learn towards either ways: Either the right-border will overflow to the right of the table cell, such that the values still can be read, but it will break the aesthetic value. On the other hand, the precision is not very important, so the element would end up being aligned to the right.

Comment: I also thought a bit about absolute positioning, and setting the top-attribute (as mentioned by @William), but as I understand it - if I set the top-attribute, then the elements would stay there and not "float" upwards.

Comment: if your data is dynamic css alone won't do it, you'll need javascript to make calculations and assign 'top' (and 'left') to the absolute positioned elements accordingly. No 'float'. Their parent will have to  have position:relative.

Comment: consider rethinking your design too -- you can have all in one line as small five pixel or something blocks with their values displayed separately on the hover. This way "the separate note" will also be addressed.

Comment: Thank you Zhenya, but the table is intended for printing. This is for prototyping, so I am relying on a technology I know. Future development might use ps or pdf, which should include easier methods for calculating the width of each element and thus having the lines compressed.